# Leaking shower head at the head itself under pressure

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

My shower head is leaking while under pressure. Like there is a gasket blown where the face of the shower head meets the rest of the head. Any idea why? its oval so there is no unscrewing it. if i push up on it while its on, the leak just moves to the other side of the head.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would  you add a picture of your shower head to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sounds like you need to replace it...